# Uploading large(ish) files with Jquery File Upload

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-file-upload

I'm troubleshooting an issue with uploading large (>45 MB) files to an ASP.NET application with [jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) plugin. I'll start with the filecontroller.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddFiles(Guid id, HttpPostedFileBase[] fileList, Guid fileId)
{
    var files = new List<object>();

    foreach (var file in fileList)
    {
        files.Add(new
        {
            name = file.FileName,
            size = file.ContentLength
        });
    }

    return Json(new { files });
}
```

The markup

```
<div id="card-@upload.Id" class="drop-card wide" data-id="@Model.Id" data-file="@upload.Id" data-is-multiple="true">
    <form class="text-right" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input class="fileupload" type="file" name="fileList" multiple="multiple" >
            <input type="hidden" name="fileId" value="@upload.Id">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="@Model.Id">
    </form>
</div>
```

The Javascript

```
    var $t = $(".drop-card");
    var url = "/filecontroller/addfiles"
    var $fileupload = $t.find('.fileupload');
    var $form = $t.find('form');

    $fileupload
        .fileupload({
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            dropZone: $t,
            formData: $form.serializeArray(),
            singleFileUploads: false,
            autoUpload: false,
            add: function (e, data) {
                data.submit();
            },
            done: function (e, data) {
                console.log('done', data)
            }
        });
    });
```

**The Problem**

With individual or multiple small files, the `fileList` paramater and subsequent variable are populated in my controller method just fine.  With large files, it blows up when looping through `fileList` and says it's null.  This *seems* like an asynchronous issue but I can't tell how to address it.

**What I've tried**

Numerous articles suggest using `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on my form, which I've done. My parameter names line up with my form inputs and I have a `[HttpPost]` annotation on my controller method.

Note: `id` and `fileId` parameters are being populated when using breakpoints in my controller. The `fileList` is null with large files.

**Update**
This seems more and more like something server-side based on the number of `net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED` and `net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` errors I am receiving during failure..

Answer (score 0):

You try to this case:

```js
$("#BrowerfileUploadContractShedule").change(function () {
                var form = $('#formconditionContractSchedule')[0];
                var formData = new FormData(form);
                var fileUpload = $("#BrowerfileUploadContractShedule").get(0);
                var files = fileUpload.files;
                formData.append("file", files[0].name);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "Your link",
                    type: 'POST',
                    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                    data: formData,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    asnyc: false,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert(response)
                        $("#spindelayLoadData").modal("toggle");
                    }
                });
            })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formconditionContractSchedule">
       <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file"> File Test 
       <input name="file" type="file" id="BrowerfileUploadContractShedule" onchange="$('#upload-file-info-ContractSchedule').html(this.files[0].name)">
       </span>
</form>
```

You add the code below into **Web.config**

```
<system.web><httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="1073741824" maxQueryStringLength="32768" /></system.web>
```

Comment: It looks like my maxRequestLength is already set pretty high

Comment: When do you upload file,Does it show file name on the web?

Comment: I appreciate the answer but I was hoping to continue using the jquery-file-upload plugin if possible.

Comment: Ok you. If i can do, i'll help you more. I have new answer i'll send u